# Doxygen/C++ : bug with callgraph + template?

Tags: c++, templates, doxygen

I work with Ubuntu + Doxygen (+ GraphViz) and I have a problem to generate callgraphs for template class.

Here there is my test code for documentation :

```
#ifndef TEST_H_INCLUDED
#define TEST_H_INCLUDED
// ---------------------------------- //
// Doxygen callgraph OK
class Class1
{
    public:
        int f1() {return f2();}
        int f2() {return x;}
    protected:
        int x;
};
// ---------------------------------- //
// Doxygen callgraph OK
class Class2
{
    public:
        int f1();
        int f2();
    protected:
        int x;
};
int Class2::f1()
{
    return f2();
}
int Class2::f2()
{
    return x;
}
// ---------------------------------- //
// Doxygen callgraph OK
template<class T> class Class3
{
    public:
        T f1() {return f2();}
        T f2() {return x;}
    protected:
        T x;
};
// ---------------------------------- //
// Doxygen callgraph PROBLEM (no callgraph)
template<class T> class Class4
{
    public:
        T f1();
        T f2();
    protected:
        T x;
};
template<class T> T Class4<T>::f1()
{
    return f2();
}
template<class T> T Class4<T>::f2()
{
    return x;
}
// ---------------------------------- //
#endif // TEST_H_INCLUDED
```

The problem is that Doxygen generate callgraphs for f1() and f2() for Class1, Class2 and Class3 but nothing for Class4. Do you have this problem too ? Is there any solution ? Is it a problem of Doxygen or GraphViz ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Running your example I get a call graph for each `f1` for all the classes. However, I feel that we don't have all the information: running your example with the default doxygen configuration file wont generate the graphs since you have documented anything (there should be some `///` or `/** */`s litering the code). To get the caller graphs I had to set `EXTRACT_ALL` and `CALL_GRAPH` to `YES` in the configuration file. Are there any warnings displayed while running doxygen?